# Webcam not working

Tags: webcam, dell-inspiron

I have a dell inspiron 1520 with a integrated web cam ,vista was the OS that came up with the system , i have moved to xp and have downloaded all the necessary driver for xp from the dell drivers download.....everything is working apart from the webcam...... i have downloaded the integrated webcam driver from dell download and installed it .... it was showing an error message not able to install .... i went to the device manager and when i checked i have seen a yellow question mark for the integrated webcam..... i uninstalled and installed the driver i have downloaded from dell.... the installation went fine and when i checked back in device manager i am seeing USB Composite Device and my webcam is still not functioning.

Any suggestions whats going wrong... please help

Comment: how are you testing the webcam?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the correct driver:

**[Creative Labs Laptop Integrated Webcam](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=my&cs=mybsd1&l=en&s=bsd&releaseid=R160323&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1520&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=15135&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=17&fileid=214676)**

However, you shouldn't need it. The webcam will be automatically detected by Windows XP and the generic driver works just fine.

In case the webcam is turned off, you can enable it via <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

The Fn key combinations may not be working without this:

**[Dell QuickSet](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=my&cs=mybsd1&l=en&s=bsd&releaseid=R180759&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1520&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=2861&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=25&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=246458)**

Answer (score 0):

Dell has lauched "Dell Webcam central". Perhaps it could work on your computer.

You can google for it or download my copies at [part I](http://www.4shared.com/file/114942527/29649a97/DellWebcamCentralpart2.html) and [part II](http://www.4shared.com/file/114942527/29649a97/DellWebcamCentralpart2.html).

Comment: also you may consider remove the webcam drivers if installed on Device manager , please reboot, and  reinstall your new driver!

Comment: consider editing your original response with your additional information.

Comment: reading the question we can see bobby knows how to remove current drivers and of course install. the only additional stuff is to say: bobby, first of all install winrar :)